# SQL Server Agent job fails to run SSIS package, but the package runs fine manually

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis, sql-server-agent, ssis-2012

SQL Server Agent job fails to run SSIS package, but the package runs fine manually
The SQL server is SQL Server 2012. 
The job has been working for a long time fine. This is the first time when it failed. We haven’t changed anything.

Error Message:

Executed as user: Domain\SQLServiceAcct. Started:  5:36:22 AM  Finished: 6:56:31 AM  Elapsed:  4809.11 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

Information about the job:

It has a proper SSIS Package Credential (we use the service account as identity)
The Job runs as: Proxy SSIS Exec
Package source: SSIS Package Store
Log on the server: Use Windows Authentication (we use service account)
Package: \MSDB\FOO_BAR\name of the job

Is this something to do with the SQL Server agent?

Comment: Can you please expand the error log and get the details, also what errors do you see in your system/app log in eventvwr.msc?  Yes, it could be related to SQL Agent.  SQL Agent runs under it's own service account but in many different areas are options to execute parts as different users as well.  Manually it's running under your name

Comment: Did the service account's password change recently?  If so, you may have to use configuration manager to stop/start the SQL Agent Service with the correct credentials.  Does the Service account have access to the objects/directories that the package touches?

Comment: @AliRazeghi...I can't expand the error log. but The error in system/app log is Package"Packagename" faild. Event ID 12291.

Comment: @MguerraTorres...No we haven't change passwords. Yes the service account have access. It has been working for long time until now

Comment: @SQL_DBA_Bini - If it's been working up until now, then you're looking for something that's changed. It could be something about the system (like a password change, or a permissions change on an account), or something with the data the package works with. If you see nothing in logs, then you may want to add more logging to the package to tell you exactly where it's failing. I assume that you know it runs fine manually because you've run it manually since the job failed the first time.